# Как спрятать Toolbar во фрагмент

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-toolbar

Есть фрагмент. во фрагменте есть toolbar

**Вот разметка фрагмента:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layour">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_default" />  <!-- TOOLBAR -->

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/layout_order">
            <!-- ОСНОВНОЙ КОНТЕНТ ФРАГМЕНТА -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/secondary_text"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Разметка Toolbar:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/layout_logo"
            android:transitionName="logo">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/steering"
                android:src="@drawable/steering" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Внутри фрагмента активирую toolbar:**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_order, container, false);


        initToolbar(rootView);

        ....

        return rootView;
    }


    private void initToolbar(View v) {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");

        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

В итоге, начиная с Android 5.0 все хорошо, Toolbar отображается.
Но с SDK ниже просто отсутсвует и все.
Причем NAvigationDrawer работает.

Кто сталкивался с данной проблемой?

**UPD**
Я пробовал перенести toolbar в Activity, все нормально, отображается как надо. Только мне надо в отдельном фрагменте.

Comment: А если перенести `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` в `onResume()` фрагмента?..

Comment: Никчему не привело. :(

Comment: А если не пользовать include а по старинке, дедовскими способами?

Comment: Так тоже пробовал. Никаких результатов.

Comment: Других вариантов нема(